# Within the HTML <select> how can I pre-fill a drop-down if I already have data for a contact?

Tags: html, forms, drop-down-menu, html-select

I need to have a 'please select' on the drop-down which shouldn't be selectable, however when adding this it then doesn't display my existing data and is defaulting to just 'please select'

With the 'please select' this is the functionality I want to happen - that it's the text shown in the initial box, and then also it's not an option in the dropdown - but this should only show if I do not have a value already for the contact.

```
<select value="@GENDER@" name="cd_GENDER" ng-init="GENDER = '@GENDER@' || '1'" ng-model="GENDER" id="gender" disabled="">
  <option selected="" hidden="" disabled="" value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="female">Female</option>
<option value="male">Male</option>
 <option value="other">Other</option>
  <option value="prefer to not say">Prefer to not say</option>
</select>
```

if I remove `hidden`, `disabled`, `selected` - then my value of 'female' is displayed because that already exists

```
<select name="cd_GENDER" ng-init="GENDER = '@GENDER@' || '1'" ng-model="GENDER" id="gender" disabled="">
  <option value="0">Please Select</option>
<option value="female">Female</option>
<option value="male">Male</option>
 <option value="other">Other</option>
  <option value="prefer to not say">Prefer to not say</option>
</select>
```

I'm expecting

1. A new contact comes to the form, they should see 'please select' and then the dropdown will have the 4 options
2. A returning contact visits the form, they have already previously provided 'Other' - 'Other' should be displayed for that contact

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have something on your page selecting the value. You might be able to quickly verify that if the same value is still selected after changing the order of the options in the html...

You might want to refer to: Firefox ignores option selected="selected"

so u can try this one it's will be fine for you

```
    <select id="gender" name="cd_GENDER" ng-init="GENDER = '@GENDER@' || '1'" ng-model="GENDER">
        <option value="0" hidden>Please Select</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
        <option value="prefer to not say">Prefer to not say</option>
    </select>
    <script>
        function getSelectionOption(id) {
            let selectionGender = document.getElementById(id);
            let index = selectionGender.options.selectedIndex;
            let valueSelection = selectionGender.options[index].value;
            alert(valueSelection);
        }
        function selection(id, value = 0, disabled = false) {
            let selectionGender = document.getElementById(id);
            let selectedOption = value;
            console.log(selectionGender.options);
            lengthGender = selectionGender.options.length;
            for (let i = 0; i < lengthGender; i++) {
                let optionValue = selectionGender.options[i].value;
                if (optionValue == selectedOption) {
                    console.log(optionValue);
                    selectionGender.options.selectedIndex = i;
                }
            }
            if (disabled) {
                selectionGender.setAttribute('disabled', true);
            } else {
                selectionGender.removeAttribute('disabled');
            }
        }
        selection('gender');
        // selection('gender','other',true);
    </script>
```